# Naming file when sending PDF via AirDrop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pdf

If sending a PDF generated from an app through AirDrop in iOS 7, any ideas how to set the title of the document?

The usual search on SO and documents have not answered my question

```
 NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userCert_%@",self.certificate.reference];

 NSData *cert = self.pdfData;

     UIActivityViewController *activityCtr = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[cert]
                                                                              applicationActivities:nil];


 NSMutableArray *excludedActivities = [self iOS6Activities].mutableCopy;
    [excludedActivities addObject:UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];
    [excludedActivities addObject:UIActivityTypePostToFlickr];
    [excludedActivities addObject:UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
    [excludedActivities addObject:UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];
    [activityCtr setExcludedActivityTypes:excludedActivities];

    [self presentViewController:activityCtr
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to share NSData, you have to wrap it in an object that conforms to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol, and implement the optional protocol method `activityViewController:dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType:`. This however will not solve the problem of specifying the file name as it seems in this case the system will generate one based upon the UTI and some hash.

If you write the data out to a file and share a NSURL fileURL instead of the NSData, the filename you gave the file will be used and is what is shown in the alert on the receiving device. Even in this case, it might be worth wrapping the URL in a UIActivityItemSource conforming object as it will enable you to provide things such as a preview image using the optional protocol method `activityViewController:thumbnailImageForActivityType:suggestedSize:`.